# Call a javascript function onclick using vba on a webpasge

Tags: excel, webbrowser-control, browser-automation, ie-automation, vba

Hi I'm trying to figure out a way to call a java script mapped to a button using VBA as part of the web page data entry automation.
Following is the code from the site and also the code that I'm working on.

Browser code :

```
<input name="reportIIS" value="Select" class="button" onclick="javascript: onSelect('/cooapp/servlet/CooMainServlet?command=SelectProgram&amp;programType=IIS')" type="button">
```

VBA

```
Sub login() 'this is working

    Const Url$ = "https://www.mast-technicalservices.com/ecp/index2.jsp"

    Dim UserName As String, Password As String, LoginData As Workbook, elems As Object


    UserName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
    Password = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")

    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie

        .navigate Url
        ieBusy ie
        .Visible = True

        Dim oLogin As Object, oPassword As Object
        Set oLogin = .document.getElementsByName("ecp_param_userId")(0)
        Set oPassword = .document.getElementsByName("ecp_param_password")(0)

        oLogin.Value = UserName
        oPassword.Value = Password
        .document.forms(0).submit

        ieBusy ie

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        ' After 2sec wait time I need to click the said button to navigate to the next page



    End With

End Sub

Sub ieBusy(ie As Object)
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4
            DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try using a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) to select the target element. Then `.fireEvent` method on selected element using the event name.

---

**CSS selector:**

Select the element with selector

```
input[name='reportIIS']
```

Which means `input` tag with attribute `name` `="reportIIS"`

[image: CSS selector]

So,

```
Dim elem As Object
Set elem = ie.document.querySelector("input[name='reportIIS']")
```

---

**.fireEvent:**

Then trigger the associated event with:

```
elem.fireEvent "onclick"
```

or

```
elem.fireEvent "onSelect"
```

It looks like it is the former.

---

More info on [.fireEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ms536423(v=vs.94)) method:

> `fireEvent` method: Fires a specified event on the object.
>
> Syntax: `object.fireEvent(bstrEventName, pvarEventObject,
>   pfCancelled)`

It has a boolean return value which if `TRUE` tells you the event was successfully fired.

---

[`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method:

> The `Document` method `querySelector()` returns the first `Element`
>   within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of
>   selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.
>
> Syntax: `element = document.querySelector(selectors)`;  <== note the
>   ";"  is not used in VBA